# Why would currentList be unavailable on this ListAdapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I am replacing a regular RecyclerView with a ListAdapter.
I am trying to implement a delete on swipe on the list within a fragment.

I have created the following ListAdapter class, the code for which is as follows:

```
class NewsAdapter(private val listener: OnItemClickListener) : ListAdapter<Article, NewsAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticleViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemArticlePreviewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ArticleViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentArticle = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(currentArticle)
    }

    inner class ArticleViewHolder(private val binding: ItemArticlePreviewBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        init {
            binding.apply {
                root.setOnClickListener {
                    val position = adapterPosition
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        val article = getItem(position)
                        listener.onItemClick(article)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fun bind(article: Article) {
            binding.apply {
                Glide.with(itemView.context).load(article.urlToImage).into(ivArticleImage)
                tvSource.text = article.source.name
                tvTitle.text = article.title
                tvDescription.text = article.description
                tvPublishedAt.text = article.publishedAt
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    * Had to create my own function here since for some reason,
    * newsAdapter.currentList is not working in any fragment
    * */
    fun getArticleAt(position: Int): Article {
        return getItem(position)
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(article: Article)
    }

    class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem.url == newItem.url 
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

Within the fragment where this list resides, I have the following:

```
...
lateinit var newsAdapter: NewsAdapter
...
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
        ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
        ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                val article = newsAdapter.getArticleAt(position) // this works, but it is not what I want
                viewModel.deleteArticle(article)
                Snackbar.make(view, "Article successfully deleted.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .apply {
                        setAction("Undo") {
                            viewModel.saveArticle(article)
                        }
                        show()
                    }
            }

        }).attachToRecyclerView(rvSavedNews)
...
}
...
```

Notice above, that I had to call:

```
val article = newsAdapter.getArticleAt(position)
```

within the fragment, since for some reason, I cannot use currentList as follows:

```
val article = newsAdapter.currentList[position]
```

The delete on swipe works just fine from what I can tell, however, I don't think I am always getting the most current list. Note: calling submitList on my adapter works just fine for other purposes. currentList seems to not be callable and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Weird, does ``getCurrentList()`` work?

Comment: @cactustictacs ```getCurrentList()``` does not work either, tried it and I even had a look at the ListAdapter.java Android class and I don't see either currentList, nor getCurrentList() being available!

Comment: Maybe you're using some outdated version of the library from before that was added? Try updating your jetpack dependencies to their latest versions.

Comment: I don't think that's it. I have updated my gradle dependencies, and that did not fix the problem.

Comment: Are you actually using the Jetpack/androidx version of RecyclerView in your dependencies? You might be using an old version that comes as a dependency for another library - I noticed your ``ListAdapter`` type definition takes two parameters (``Article`` and a ``ViewHolder``) but the current one only takes a ``ViewHolder``: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter . Like @Tenfour04 says, it might have been added later - the original ``ListAdapter`` interface didn't have that method: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter?hl=en